# How can I install Angular universal on a full stand alone Angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have removed the app.module from my angular app in order to have a full stand alone app.

In my main.ts file I added the follwing:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes))]
})
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

My applications runs fine without any module file; however, I donlt know how to add Angular Universal since it will not find the app.module.ts file and Angular universal uses the server.module...

I added the following to the main.ts file:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes), BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }))]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

but I have to replace the app.module on the server.ts file and the app.component won't work

Answer (score 0):

according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/zqkomk/does_standalone_components_support_ssr_universal/), standalone components are not supported yet in SSR

Comment: As of v16, Universal now supports standalone.